# Building Java UI to control diodes through Nabduino(PIC18J67) - any examples?

Tags: java, interface, arduino, rxtx

I am building a Nabduino(which is a kind of Arduino) to control some lights and i want to make a interface, possibly in Java.

I have been looking for examples to interface to a Nabduino or Arduino with Java, but can not find any useable ones.

I am looking for someone who did something like this or some examples of how this can be done the best way.

/Kasper